# Can the hostname of a synchronization source be changed in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, sync

I use the built-in "Offline Files and Folders" functionality of Windows 7 to sync my notebook with my main workstation (also Windows 7). Lately I had to move into another building across the street resulting in new IP addresses for both my notebook and my workstation (also from a different subnet). Hostnames changed as well.

Had I thought of that beforehand, I had simply synchronized both computers and then set up a new synchronization partnership with the new hostnames/addresses. Unfortunately, I did not.

So my question essentially is: Can I somehow change to which host Windows tries to connect to synchronize the cached offline files?